@await RenderSectionAsync giving "Cannot await 'method group' "
I am creating a razor application consisting of two simple user inputs and two navigation tabs with 'save' and 'cancel' button for the user inputs.
I have pasted below part of the _Layout.cshtml code giving the titled error. Am I missing something ?
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody ( )
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - Landing Page
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync ( "Scripts" , required: false )
</body>
</html>

Tried reading the MS CS4001 doc but there's nothing there regarding this error. Pls help. Thanks!

Inside the @await RenderSectionAsync ( "Scripts" , required: false ) line you have a misplaced space inside it which caused the issue.
I suggest you could remove the space use it like below and then it will work well.
  @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)


hi Zhang , I tried that as well, it didn't work. Still throws the same Error "Cannot await 'method group' "

@RenderBody ( ) you also have this issue, use this instead @RenderBody( )

Thanks a lot Zhang, it worked! I have to be careful on doing formatting of the file.
